# Matplotlib animation file not playable when Python program is aborted

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, video

On the page https://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/moviewriter.html a Python script is presented to produce an animation file `"writer_test.mp4`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("Agg")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as manimation

FFMpegWriter = manimation.writers['ffmpeg']
metadata = dict(title='Movie Test', artist='Matplotlib',
                comment='Movie support!')
writer = FFMpegWriter(fps=15, metadata=metadata)

fig = plt.figure()
l, = plt.plot([], [], 'k-o')

plt.xlim(-5, 5)
plt.ylim(-5, 5)

x0, y0 = 0, 0

with writer.saving(fig, "writer_test.mp4", 100):
    for i in range(100):
        x0 += 0.1 * np.random.randn()
        y0 += 0.1 * np.random.randn()
        l.set_data(x0, y0)
        writer.grab_frame()
```

However, when the program is aborted the video file `"writer_test.mp4` is unplayable.

I often have this problem whilst programming large simulation scripts. Even when a script fails to finish, I would still like to see the video as far as the script ran before it was aborted or interrupted.

Is there a way to modify the code such that the video file `"writer_test.mp4` is still playable even when the Python program is aborted before finishing?

Comment: Why is the program aborted? Is due to a python error inside the loop or something external? In the former case a try-except clause could help. Also if the frames are actually written to the file maybe there is repair tool for mp4 files available somewhere?

Comment: It's not about this particular script, but just any script in general in which a matplotlib animation is produced. So the reason for a script to be aborted could be anything. The essence is that the movie should remain playable even after any error occurs. But indeed, a `try-except` construct could help. Besides that, it seems that, at least under Windows 7, the file size remains at 1 kB, so I don't think a repair tool will help.